# DocuSign Envelop Correction and DocuSign Limits (Violations) for Go Live

Tags: docusignapi

We have ASP.ET MVC Web application. We are using Docusign SDK For C#.
We are planning to go Live with DocuSign Integration and We looked at DocuSign limits (specially 15 minutes get request limit).
We need an advice on how to avoid violation in Envelop Correction scenario. Steps are as given below.

1. Get status of envelop
2. Get recipients of envelop and show it user in the GUI
3. User updates email in the GUI and submits form
4. On backend we **Get recipients again** with all tabs and custom fields, Update email address
5. Call Update recipients method

You see on number 4. It is 15 minutes violation. How to handle this scenario?

We don't want to create Whole mechanism for Saving/Caching DocuSign Recipients data and statuses. As those statuses can change from DocuSign  or some of the recipient can decline or void envelop. We want to fetch latest recipient data to update on the time of execution.

Comment: @JamesZ I have updated question

Comment: why can't the form include all the information ? the information can then be sent to the back-end from the front-end instead of making another API call.
Another option is that you use the same back-end for both with a session. The session allows the call to go to the same server before/after the user updates the email and that server would have the information in flight (in memory). This is not caching just normal client/server approach.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Inbar that you could store the results of the first get_recipients call. You could either store it in the user's session state (server side) or send it all to the browser and then have the browser return it.

I'd go with [session state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Saving data in the session state isn't a big deal.

Re:

> As those statuses can change from DocuSign or some of the recipient can decline or void envelope.

So you're worried that while the application user is updating an email address, the envelope will be declined by a recipient?

In that case you could lock the envelope while your user is updating it. Or you could not send the envelope until after the user has updated it. Or if you get an error while updating the recipients, that would be the time to do the extra recipients_get.

Comment: Thanks @Larry, As you may know that one envelope has Many recipients and many anchor Tabs Data. I think that will be Bad Design if we send that much data to Brower. I have different server for backend and different Web applications servers.